# GTK equivalent of Windows Forms and System.Drawing functions such as Control.Location from System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, gtk, gtk3, gtk#

I'm trying to find the GTK equivalent of `Control.Location` from `System.Windows.Forms` and `Point` from `System.Drawing` and how to implement them. Currently I have a project that I'm migrating over from Windows Forms to GTK that has piano keys that are graphically drawn by the System.Drawing (which I need to replace it).

One part of the code that uses `Control.Location` and `Point` is here:

```
        private void InitializePianoKeys()
        {
            #region Guard

            if(keys.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            #endregion

            int whiteKeyWidth = Width / whiteKeyCount;
            int blackKeyWidth = (int)(whiteKeyWidth * BlackKeyScale);
            int blackKeyHeight = (int)(Height * BlackKeyScale);
            int offset = whiteKeyWidth - blackKeyWidth / 2;
            int n = 0;
            int w = 0;

            int widthsum = 0; // Sum of white keys' width
            int LastWhiteWidth = 0; // Last white key width
            int remainder = Width % whiteKeyCount; // The remaining pixels
            int counter = 1;
            double step = remainder != 0 ? whiteKeyCount / (double)remainder : 0; // The ternary operator prevents a division by zero

            while (n < keys.Length)
            {
                if (KeyTypeTable[keys[n].NoteID] == KeyType.White)
                {

                    keys[n].Height = Height;
                    keys[n].Width = whiteKeyWidth;

                    if (remainder != 0 && counter <= whiteKeyCount && Convert.ToInt32(step * counter) == w)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        keys[n].Width++;
                    }
                    // See the Location property of black keys to understand
                    widthsum += LastWhiteWidth;
                    LastWhiteWidth = keys[n].Width;
                    keys[n].Location = new Point(widthsum, 0);

                    w++;
                    //n++; // Move?
                }
                else
                {
                    keys[n].Height = blackKeyHeight;
                    keys[n].Width = blackKeyWidth;
                    keys[n].Location = new Point(widthsum + offset);
                    //keys[n].Location = new Point(widthsum + offset - keys[n - 1].Width); // By this way, eliminates the LastWhiteWidth var
                    keys[n].BringToFront();
                    //n++; // Move?
                }
                n++; // Moved
            }
        }
```

Now I do suspect the GTK equivalent of `Point` is `Gdk.Point`, but unsure since this part of the code `keys[n].Location = new Point(widthsum + offset);` seems to highlight an issue around `(widthsum + offset)`.

Also, I'm curious as to what the GTK equivalent of `BringToFront()` is? I have heard that it's `Gdk.Window`, so I tried replacing `keys[n].BringToFront();` with `keys[n].Window.Raise();`, while the compiler seems to accept it, I'm not sure if it will make the black piano keys in front of the white ones, because what `BringToFront()` did was place the black piano keys in front of the white piano keys in Windows Forms, which wasn't a window at all.

Now, for the next part of the code that the compiler seems to be highlighting:

```
        public void Send(ChannelMessage message)
        {
            if (message.Command == ChannelCommand.NoteOn &&
                message.Data1 >= LowNoteID && message.Data1 <= HighNoteID)
            {
                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    BeginInvoke(noteOnCallback, message);
                }
                else
                {
                    noteOnCallback(message);
                }
            }
            else if (message.Command == ChannelCommand.NoteOff &&
                message.Data1 >= LowNoteID && message.Data1 <= HighNoteID)
            {
                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    BeginInvoke(noteOffCallback, message);
                }
                else
                {
                    noteOffCallback(message);
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see here, this is the part where I'm trying to find the GTK equivalent of `Control.InvokeRequired` and `Control.BeginInvoke`, and to learn how to implement them correctly.

Also, I made PianoControl as a `Gtk.Widget` class, along with every other class in the project, while I was migrating the code from Windows Forms to GTK, it was originally a `System.Windows.Forms.Control` class.

And just before I finished writing this, I also came across another issue:

```
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                foreach (PianoKey key in keys)
                {
                    key.Dispose();
                }
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

Apparently `Dispose` is defined as a `Gtk.Widget` both in this code and in the other file PianoControl.PianoKey.cs as this code:

```
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if(disposing)
                {
                    onFillPaint.Dispose();
                    offFillPaint.Dispose();
                }

                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
```

The original implementation used `Control.Dispose`, but what I'm confused about, is that `Gtk.Widget` won't accept the same parameters with an override, where as the original implementation did. Because the compiler says PianoControl already defines a member called 'Dispose' with the same parameter types.

Thank you so much!

Comment: This (These ?) question is kind of confusing. For potentially better results, I would suggest narrowing down the issue and making small and complete examples of what you need, instead of printing code from an existing program. Also, please go one question at a time.

Comment: Have you tried using Cairo to draw the keyboard on a DrawingArea instead? Might be easier overall.